# greet is not a function (However It declared in mongoose file as a Schema method) (JS) -

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is the mongoose file that I run through Node:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopApp')
.then(()=>{
    console.log('CONNECTION OPEN!!!')
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log('HO NO ERROR!!!')
    console.log(err)
})

// alternative syntax for Schema, now we can add additional information. the require.
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 20   // Schema options
    },
    price: {
        type: Number, // number character inside a string will be accepted and the 
opposite also!!!!!!!!!!
        min: [0, 'Price must be positive'] // minimum character from SchemaTypes options 
and then error msg
    },
    onSale: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    categories: {
        //[String] which means: it should be an array only consisting of strings
    type: [String]

    }, // 
    qty: {
        online: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        inStore: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    },
    size: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['S', 'M', 'L'] // can be only one of this values, else it return an error
    }
})


const product = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);
//instance methods
// someSchema.methods.findSimilarType = function() {
    //...
//}

productSchema.methods.greet = function(){
    console.log('HELLO!!! HI!!! HOWDY!!!')
} // we want to use regular function

/*const bike = new product({name: 'Cycling Jersy', price: 18.50, categories: ['Cycling', 
' Safety'], size: 'XL'}) // the mongo will ignore the color property
bike.save()
.then(data=>{
    console.log('IT WORKED!')
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log('HO NO ERROR!!!')
    console.log(err)
})*/

product.findOneAndUpdate({name: 'Tire pump'}, {price: 1}, {new: true, runValidators: 
true})  // Schema constraints don't work with updating ( it below minimum price),
// you need to set ---> runValidators: true!!!!!
.then(data=>{
    console.log('IT WORKED!')
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log('HO NO ERROR!!!')
    console.log(err)
})
```

---

in node.js I loaded this mongoose file and created an instance of the model and tried to run the function greet on it.

```
const p = new product({name: 'Big Bag', price: 10})
p.greet()
```

In the background mongod and mongo are running both on the prompt.

I get a message 'greet is not a function'.

Comment: The order may matter. What if you declared the instance method before creating the model?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment.I have tried to do that - the result is the same.
I notice that I can see the function on node.js, if I make the function an IIFE function on mongoose, but if I write on node - p.greet() - its the same problem.

Comment: productSchema.statics.fireSale = function(){
    this.updateMany({}, {onSale: true, price: 0})
    return this.save();
};

I add this method and when im tring to use it on 'product' (the model itself), I get an error --> product.fireSale is not a function.

why its hapening?

Comment: I was able to get this working locally after moving the definition of `greet` before the call to `mongoose.model`. What change did you try?

Comment: Hey.
I changed the instance name, from ' p' to another name - now the greet() being called successfully.
yet,  fireSale() isnt.